# How configure LightInject in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, inversion-of-control, simple-injector, light-inject

I use SimpleInjector in mvc with this code

```
public static class SimpleInjectorInitializer
{
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        var container = new Container();
        InitializeContainer(container);
        container.RegisterMvcControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        container.Verify();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));
    }

    private static void InitializeContainer(Container container)
    {
        container.Register<IPersonRepository, PersonEntityRepository>();
    }
}
```

but now I want to test **LightInject** Ioc in my mvc application but How ?

I wrote this code

```
[assembly: WebActivator.PostApplicationStartMethod(typeof(LightInjectInitializer), "InitializeLI")]

public static class LightInjectInitializer
{
    public static void InitializeLI()
    {
        var container = new ServiceContainer();            
        InitializeContainer(container);
        container.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        container.EnableMvc();
    }

    private static void InitializeContainer(ServiceContainer container)
    {
        container.Register(typeof(PersonEntityRepository), typeof(IPersonRepository), new PerScopeLifetime());

    }
}
```

[image]

but show me this error

```
No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
```

Can anyone help me for writing equivalent code that working in MVC ?

**Sample Code :** [Download](http://1drv.ms/1qJG5Q8)

Comment: Any particular reason you are switching to Light Inject? Any feature in particular that you are missing in Simple Injector?

Comment: please see benchmark http://www.palmmedia.de/blog/2011/8/30/ioc-container-benchmark-performance-comparison

Comment: I'm familiar with that benchmark. Is your only reason one of performance? Do note that LightInject is just marginally faster than Simple Injector. You will see no measurable performance difference in any real-life application.

Comment: I agree with what you said - But be happy if I learn how to work with the library - Can you resolve my problem or not ?

Comment: No, I can not. I built Simple Injector and can tell you anything about that. I have no experience with LightInject.

Comment: wowowow, simpleinjector is awesome , I love it

Answer (score 4):

I am the author of LightInject and would like to help you out.

This static initialize method? Where is it called from. 
The reason that you get this error is probably because the initialize code did not execute.

If you would like further assistance, it would be valuable to see what you have in global.asax.cs.

This page also contains information about how to set this up.

http://www.lightinject.net/#mvc

Comment: [assembly: WebActivator.PostApplicationStartMethod(typeof(LightInjectInitializer), "InitializeLI")] - I added this attribute and used onion architecture

Comment: Can you verify that the method is executed by setting a breakpoint?

Comment: yes I can, see my post again , If you want, I can upload my sample

Comment: It would be great if you could upload the project somewhere.

Comment: That link target (#mvc) is no longer valid. It may have moved to: http://www.lightinject.net/mvc/ though there is not a lot of information there either.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the controller registration line to:

```
container.RegisterControllers(typeof(MVCApplicationNamespace.Controllers.HomeController).Assembly);
```